# Potential along axis of a charged coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

[image]

I want to calculate the potential $\Phi$ along the $z$-axis of a circular coil with charge $Q$ and radius $R$.
My idea was to solve it using Laplace's equation in cylindrical coordinates:
$$ \nabla^2 \Phi = -4\pi \rho (\vec{r}) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{r} \frac{ \partial \Phi }{ \partial r } + \frac{ \partial^2 \Phi }{ \partial r^2 } +\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial \theta^2}+ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial z^2} = -4\pi \rho (\vec{r})$$

Since we are only interested in the potential $\Phi(z)$ on the $z$-axis Laplace's equation simplifies to:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial z^2} = 0 $$
The solution to this differential equation is:
$$ \Phi(z) = a z + b $$ 
I set the potential at $z=0$ to zero
$$ \Rightarrow \Phi(z) = az $$
Now I am pretty sure that this result is wrong, since the solution is linear.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The radial derivatives don’t have to vanish on the $z$-axis. And normally one takes the potential to be zero at infinity.

Comment: It appears that the equation you are using applies to a distributed charge.  Where does the fact that the charge is on a ring come onto your calculations?

Comment: @R.W.Bird  You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since electric potential is a scaler, the potential on the $z$ axis is just
$-\frac{kQ}{ \sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}$
with the zero at infinity. 
If you want the zero to be at $z=0$, subtract $\frac{-kQ}{R}$.

Comment: But if the solution to the potential is $\Phi (z) = \frac{-kQ}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2}}$ then the electric field can be calculated by integrating this function. Which implies that the electric field has the form of $\sinh^{-1}(\frac{z}{R})$. This would imply that the electric field diverges when $z$ goes to infinity. Which can't be right, or am I missing something?

Comment: The electric field is the gradient of the potential;  In this case the derivative with respect to z.  By the way, from a very large distance, a ring of charge looks like a point charge, and the field does diverge.

Comment: The electric field of  a point charge is $E \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$ and its Potential $\Phi \propto \frac{1}{r}$. However, both converge so I don't really understand what you mean that the field diverges. I saw my mistake, I should have taken the derivative (and considered the negative sign). By taking the derivative the field converges which solves my question

Comment: When I say that the field diverges, I'm suggesting that it spreads out.  I'm guessing that you are saying that the functions converge on a value of zero.